# XCode 4 Step into doesn't work

Tags: xcode

Im using XCode 4 and seeing a problem with debugging that did not exist in 3.x.

I am putting a breakpoint at a line where I call an object method.

```
Product *p = [[Product alloc] init]; 
[p  print];  <-- Put a breakpoint here
```

After control stops at that line, I try to step into the method (F7). But nothing happens. System just skips over the line and goes to the next line (same behavior as Step Over).

Step into works fine for plain C language projects. The problem is with Objective-C methods. How do I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, looking forward for an answer

Comment: Welcome to Xcode 4. I switched back after 2 days of using that piece of garbage (Xcode 4).

Comment: There is also nothing written in pdf file attached "what's new in xcode 4" whereas step in, step out are the best way to trace the bug and program control. How could apple ignore it in xcode4 whereas it is present in xcode3.x :(. Hoping to see it's solution.

Comment: I have this problem, too. Not always, but far too often to not go dig for a fix.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Xcode5. It works in other projects, however "Step into" doesnt work in my current project. I suspect there are some compiler settings that prevents stepping into.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this will help -- Go into system preferences, and under the Keyboard general settings ensure that the "Use all F1 F2 etc. as standard function keys" option is checked.

F7 started to work for me after I checked that.

Hope that helps...

Comment: This was exactly the problem I had! Although it is not the solution to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Check that the instance is not nil before trying to step into it's instance method.  As embarrassing as it may seem, we all do it occasionally.

Comment: LOL. Totally just did this after restarting and all.

Comment: It is true. If you find your Xcode directly pass by the line of code you intent to step in, check if the owner of the method is nil.

Answer (score 2):

Stepping into ObjC method calls is not always possible. The way it was explained to me, there are internal runtime data structures that must be in a consistent state in order to reliably step into an ObjC method. If those internals happen to be in an inconsistent state when the program stops at your breakpoint, stepping in in the debugger will fail, and it will step over the call instead. This was also true in Xcode 3, and really has little or nothing to do with Xcode, but is an ObjC runtime and debugger issue. I estimate anecdotally (working in Xcode full-time for 3+ years) that stepping into an ObjC method call fails ~5% of the time.  I find that it happens most often when it will be the most inconvenient to me. :)

That said, if you're NEVER able to step into ANY ObjC method call, then there's likely another problem, as I've been able to step into ObjC method calls many times with Xcode 4, and don't see this problem any more or less often than I did with Xcode 3.

Comment: I would say that with XCode 4 step into doesn't work over 95% of the time.

Comment: I completely disagree with the statement that this has nothing to do with Xcode, as it differs so drastically between the versions. I never, once, had this in Xcode 3, and right now it's so bad I'm actually searching Stackoverflow for a way to fix it.

Comment: If you're seeing different behavior, I encourage you to file a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

fn+f7 always works for me. Although step into in Obj-C is kinda weird from time to time. You'd better set more breakpoints if you know where the code is heading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about OSX to understand why this is fubar but I just tried changing the default key bindings to f13-f17 for all the usual bindings of pause/continue, step into/out of etc.  Works for me.  Pretty sucky QA on the XCode4 team possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to the gdb debugger works for me. Go to Edit Schemes, the Info tab for the Run phase, change from LLDB to GDB.

It's still not perfect. In particular it seems you have to use "Step into instruction" (with the appropriate key, or holding ctrl while hitting the step button) a lot if nothing happens, and to see registers and so on you have to use the gdb command line within the Xcode windows.

Comment: Apparently it's not possible to switch from LLDB to GDB anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28927949/2848676

Answer (score 0):

Remove the particular file and add the file again. This fixes my problem.