# How do I switch from lldb to gdb debugger types?

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, lldb

I have been looking around for quite a while trying to figure out how to switch from lldb to gdb and could not find anything on how to switch between the 2 in Xcode 6.1. I am trying to debug my app and I might be able to figure it out if I use gdb instead of lldb but I don't know if it will help me.

Any suggestions on which type of debugging is better and how to switch between the 2. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger for Xcode 6 is lldb, there is no switching to gdb.

There is no reason to need gdb. What is your problem with lldb, most of the commands are the same.

See: [LLDB to GDB Command Map](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) and [The LLDB Debugger](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html).

Comment: I was just having some trouble with the lldb debugger and wanted to know if gdb is easier to understand or use or not.

Comment: It is not easier. Both gdb and lldb are "Old School" and cryptic.

Comment: "There is no reason to need gdb" - except that lldb does not have support for some DWARF-2 features, while gdb does. The library code I'm trying to debug was compiled with gcc, and it runs fine on the iOS device, but lldb gets confused and doesn't know how to handle the format. So gdb is necessary.

Comment: FYI XCode 7.2 lldb gets the alignment of structures wrong sometimes. I would like access to gdb as well.

Comment: LLDB not use UTF-8 Cyrylic

Comment: "There is no reason to need gdb": My microcontroller only supports gdb :/